# Calling a parent ViewController's method from a subview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm stuck at this for a hour..

I have a ViewController which implements a `Method1`

In this ViewController, I add a subview by:

```
barView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BarView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[barView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 40)];
[self.view addSubview:barView];
```

This works, in the BarView.m, I have a button which when clicked, will call `Method1` in the parent ViewController.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressedMethod1 {
    [(id)self.superview Method1];        // This line is definitely wrong.
}
```

I know I'm missing something.
Anyone can help explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first code snippet is wrong as you are sending `initWithFrame` to an object already initialised by loading from a nib. Surely the view in the nib already has the right frame so this line is unnecessary?

As for the actual question, you're calling the method on the viewcontroller's view rather than the viewcontroller itself. You should be connecting the button in your view to an action in your view controller (since you're loading the nib with owner self, you can do this in IB).